# Can SCALE compact encoding be used with `Option<T>`? If so, how exactly?

Tags: scale-codec

I can't find anything on how to use the compact encoding of integers with `Option<...>`. Is this possible?

And to elaborate, if I do something like this:

```rust
#[pallet::call]
... {
    fn my_dispatchable(origin: OriginFor<T>, #[pallet::compact] my_option: Option<u128>) -> DispatchResult {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then I get the following error:

```
the trait `From<parity_scale_codec::Compact<std::option::Option<u128>>>` is not implemented for `std::option::Option<u128>`
```

This sounds like it's not possible to compactly encode options of integers. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because you apply `#[pallet::compact]` attribute to the type `Option<u128>`. `u128` can be represented as compact. `Option<u128>` can't though, since it's an option.

In this case, to make it work you will need to remove the `#[pallet::compact]` attribute and then change the type to `Option<Compact<u128>>`. [`Compact`](https://docs.rs/parity-scale-codec/3.1.2/parity_scale_codec/struct.Compact.html) is a usual tuple struct and you can extract the value by the reading `.0`.

Comment: Ok, I figured as much, but how would using an `Option` of a compact integer look like in Rust?

Comment: Well, @mkl, there is no magic. The rule is always either `0` or `1` followed by the encoding of the `T` type in case of `Some`, irregardless what type `T` is. I updated the answer with an example.

Comment: What I meant is: How do I actually do this in substrate (using `pallet::compact`, for example)?

Comment: Ok, I see, I misinterpreted you. However, it is still not clear what you are asking. Do you mean you want to know how to, e.g., declare a variable that is an `Option` with an integer, that when encoded, will be represented in compact encoding when `Some`?

Comment: I'd like to use a compactly encoded `Option` as parameter for an extrinsic.

Comment: Well, in that case, it should be as easy as slapping a `pallet::compact` attribute to an argument. Here is an example: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/d79a2afd565d93bcc369aa7c80c0f4261e051929/frame/balances/src/lib.rs#L278

Comment: Thanks, I know generally how `pallet::compact` works. It just doesn't seem like it works with `Option`. Sorry, the question was badly phrased. It's now updated.

Comment: @mkl I've updated the answer.

Comment: Many thanks. That's surprisingly simple.